# Visual Studio debug with Browserify

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript, browserify, client-side

I'm getting up to speed with packaging and using Browserify because I got it to work. I can debug in the browser because the browser maps point to the .JS code.

Is there a way to get the Visual Studio to work with such bundling?

Comment: Is the new feature in VS2017 what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to debug the JavaScript or TypeScript directly in Visual Studio, I suggest you use the VS2017 which has the new feature:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

A similar issue:

[Javascript breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669163/javascript-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: I have been doing a lot of TS/JS debugging this way. The challenge is in getting all the tools to work smoothly. Browserify doesn't let me debug in the TS directly but I can work with that for now

Comment: @BobFrankston, In the old VS version, we could debug JS using the Browser debugging tool like the F11 developer tool in IE:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, from the VS2017, it added this new feature, so we could debug the JS code in VS IDE directly now even if it also have some limitation more or less. Anyway, you could choose the VS version and the debugging way you want to use in your side:)

Comment: @BobFrankston, Whether this issue has been resolved in your side? If previous reply is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer, of course, if you find other solution, please feel free to share it here:)