# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." But I can debug the code in firefox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET application that makes use of a Javascript file to manage the front-end behaviour of my web-page. Normally debugging the JS code within visual studio works without any issues. But for some reason the debugger has stopped hitting any breakpoint that I put on my JS code.

When I hover over the break point while my application is running I get the message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." And visual studio refuses to allow me to hit any breakpoints so that I can debug my code.

However if I run my application and then use Firefox's debugger I can place and trigger breakpoints perfectly fine.

The rest of my C# code works without any issues. I can place and trigger breakpoints wherever I want. This problem is solely with my JS code.

I have tried deleting my obj and bin folders, cleaning, rebuilding, updating visual studio, rebooting, checking debug configurations and an array of other Stack Overflow solutions but nothing has fixed my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

Comment: @Cid Not a duplicate, this is solely an issue for JS code, C# code works fine.

Comment: See this other possible duplicate [Javascript breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669163/javascript-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2017/42669822)