# Howto debug JavaScript inside ASP .Net Core 3.1 MVC applications (Razor view - *.cshtml)?

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, razor, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

I have latest **Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4 Enterprise**.

I've just created an **ASP .Net Core 3.1 MVC** application from a template (with default settings).

And I've added some JavaScript code to a Home Page's **Index.cshtml**:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function GetJSON_Simple() {
            var resp = [];           
            return resp;
        }

        debugger;
        var simpleData = GetJSON_Simple();

    </script>
}
```

And I'm not able to debug JavaScript code (breakpoints inside `GetJSON_Simple` function body or on `var simpleData = GetJSON_Simple()` is never hit). I've tried both Chrome and MS Edge (Chromium).

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2019) (**Debug JavaScript in dynamic files using Razor (ASP.NET)** section):

> **Place the debugger; statement where you want to break:** This causes the
>   dynamic script to stop execution and start debugging immediately while
>   it is being created.

P.S. I've already have **Tools->Options->Debugging->General** with turned on **Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)** checkbox and of course I'm compiling in Debug.

My test project is [attached](https://yadi.sk/d/ltruntk-9PrNUA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Howto debug JavaScript inside ASP .Net Core 3.1 MVC applications
>   (Razor view - *.cshtml)?

**In fact**, it is already a well-known issue. **We can not debug the js code under Net Core razor page but only for code in separate js or ts files.** See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420474/visual-studio-javascript-debugging-not-working).

**Solution**

To solve it, I suggest you could create a new single js file called `test.js` and then reference it in razor page and then you can hit into js code when you debug it.

**1)** create a file called `test.js` and migrate your js code into it:

```
 function GetJSON_Simple() {
            var resp = [];           
            return resp;
        }

        debugger;
        var simpleData = GetJSON_Simple();
```

**2)** change to use this in your cshtml file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script scr="xxx/test.js">  
    </script>
}
```

**3)** **clean** your project, then **rebuild** your project and debug it and you will hit into Js code.

Comment: Thank you. Debugging now is working even without `debugger;` line of code. Step over, Step into, Go to Definition are working. Unfortunatelly I cannot manage to make Edit and Continue working :(

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to explicitly define the source mapping name for the script directly in your javascript code via a *sourceURL* comment.

```js
<script>

...your script code

//# sourceURL=blah
</script>
```

The script in that block will show up in Chrome with the value you specified. You can then view and debug just like a normal .js file.

This is especially useful if you don't want to refactor an existing codebase that has embedded javascript in the cshtml files or really ANY codebase that has javascript loaded on the fly.

**Live Example**

You can actually see an example with the built-in javascript runner here. Just click 'Run Snippet' and then search for "blahblah" in your Page sources. You should see this: [image]

```js
alert("test");
//# sourceURL=blahblah
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in Chrome but not in firefox. (I tesetd with .Net 6)